# Different people's same SSN & DL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

let say we have a table with below column details.
now I wanted to extract only those custID's where either **SSN or DL number is same** for different custid

table

```
***CustID   SSN DL***
1111    112331  DL1234
1112    113096  DL0987
1113    113861  DL1234
1114    112331  DL2315
1115    111104  DL5443
1115    111104  DL5443
```

in this I only want 1111,1113 & 1114

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvI9E.png)

Comment: From [Oracle tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle): *Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL*. What the DBMS you really use?

Comment: Do you mean to have 1115 repeated? Is it excluded because custid is the same or because both dl and ssn are the same?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can do it in a single table scan using analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT CustID
FROM   (
  SELECT CustID,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SSN, DL) AS num_ssl_dn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SSN) AS num_ssn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DL) AS num_dl
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_ssn > num_ssl_dn
OR     num_dl  > num_ssl_dn;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( CustID, SSN, DL ) AS
SELECT 1111, 112331, 'DL1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1112, 113096, 'DL0987' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1113, 113861, 'DL1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1114, 112331, 'DL2315' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1115, 111104, 'DL5443' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1115, 111104, 'DL5443' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTID |
> | --- |
> | 1111 |
> | 1114 |
> | 1113 |

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3793/4)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.ssn = t.ssn and t2.custid <> t.custid
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.dl = t.dl and t2.custid <> t.custid
             ) ;
```

This intentionally uses two `exists` instead of `or` in a single subquery so the optimizer can use indexes on `(ssn)` and `(dl)` if available.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table name is `table_name`, you can do it like this:

```
select custid
from   (
         select custid,
                count(distinct custid) over (partition by ssn) ssn_ct,
                count(distinct custid) over (partition by dl)   dl_ct
         from   table_name
       )
where  ssn_ct > 1 or dl_ct > 1
;
```